# Controlling bars width in matplotlib with per-month data

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, bar-chart

When I plot data sampled per month with bars, their width is very thin. If I set X axis minor locator to DayLocator(), I can see the bars width is adjusted to 1 day, but I would like them to fill a whole month.

I tried to set the minor ticks locator to MonthLocator() without effect.

**[edit]**

Maybe an example will be more explicit, here is an `ipython -pylab` example of what I mean :

```py
x = [datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 2, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 3, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 10, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 1, 0, 0)]

y = cos(numpy.arange(12) * 2)

bar(x, y)
```

This gives 12 2 pixels wide bars, I would like them to be wider and extend from month to month.

Comment: Are you talking about error bars?

Comment: No I'm talking about the bars that are generated by Axes.bar()

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just use the `width` keyword argument:

```
bar(x, y, width=30)
```

Or, since different months have different numbers of days, to make it look good you can use a sequence:

```
bar(x, y, width=[(x[j+1]-x[j]).days for j in range(len(x)-1)] + [30])
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't even think that width could take values larger than 1 :)

Comment: Setting the width by the number of days in the month is brilliant

Comment: If you are using barh, use height.

Answer (score 0):

Newer matplotlib versions (e.g. 3.7.0) can handle datetime and timedelta directly, so just computing the difference (perhaps with `np.diff()`) would suffice to compute a list of widths.

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [datetime.datetime(2008, i, 1) for i in range(1, 13)]
y = np.cos(np.arange(12) * 2)

# plot a bar chart with timedelta x-axis
plt.bar(x, y, width=[*np.diff(x), datetime.timedelta(31)]);
```

Another option is to just plot a bar chart without worrying about x-axis but add datetime data as ticklabels later.

```py
plt.bar(range(len(x)), y)
plt.xticks(range(0, len(x), 2), [d.strftime('%Y-%m') for d in x[::2]]);
```

[image: result]