# Matplotlib weekly bars are too thin when width<1.0, too thick when width>=1.0

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: My bar chart]

Why are my bars so thin? I have tried setting width to 1 and they go really thick. I'm not sure what else to try. The default thickness is 0.8, is this how it should look?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

working_runs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(1, 2, 210),
                            columns=['distance'],
                            index=pd.date_range('2019-06-01', periods=210, freq='D'))
summed = working_runs['distance'].resample('W').sum()
df = pd.DataFrame(summed)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(df.index, df.distance)
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%B %d"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%B %d"))
plt.xticks(rotation=90) 

fig = ax.get_figure()

fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(12)

plt.title('2019 Weekly Running Miles')
plt.ylabel('Distance /m')

fig.savefig("output.png")
```

I tried changing it like this:

`ax.bar(df.index, df.distance,width=1)`

0.9 does not look any different and 1.0 looks like this:

[image: thicker lines]

Comment: The thickness is expressed in the x-units. If your units are "days", you can set it to 7 to cover what seems to be the timestep of your data.

Comment: I can't see how to do that, have you got a link? (The data is weekly totals.)

Comment: Are you able to add a small sample of your data so we can recreate your issue. Since the 'usual' solution of setting width=x doesn't seem to be working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the weird behaviour, when setting width to something less than 1.0, it seems to be interpreted as a width for one day. When setting it to 1.0 or higher, it gets interpreted as a width for one week.

It seems to be a problem with how pandas and matplotlib work together.

A workaround could be to use an `edgecolor` as in `ax.bar(df.index, df.distance, width=1, edgecolor='white')` as in:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

working_runs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(1, 2, 210),
                            columns=['distance'],
                            index=pd.date_range('2019-06-01', periods=210, freq='D'))
summed = working_runs['distance'].resample('W').sum()
df = pd.DataFrame(summed)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.index, df.distance, width=1, edgecolor='white')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%B %d"))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.title('2019 Weekly Running Miles')
plt.ylabel('Distance /m')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

I experimented with staying in pandas using `df.plot.bar(y='distance', width=0.9, ax=ax)`. Formatting the dates can be accomplished by explicitly converting the `index` to a list of labels. Also in this case, the plot would look nicer using `width=1` and `edgecolor='white'`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

working_runs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(1, 2, 210),
                            columns=['distance'],
                            index=pd.date_range('2019-06-01', periods=210, freq='D'))
summed = working_runs['distance'].resample('W').sum()
df = pd.DataFrame(summed)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.bar(y='distance', width=0.9, ax=ax)
plt.xticks(range(len(df.index)),
           [t.to_pydatetime().strftime("%b %d") for t in df.index],
           rotation=90)
plt.title('2019 Weekly Running Miles')
plt.ylabel('Distance /m')
plt.show()
```

[image: example with pandas plot.bar]

Answer (score 1):

See in the documentation:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center', data=None, **kwargs)
```

here is documentation link as well: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

and related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886716/controlling-bars-width-in-matplotlib-with-per-month-data)

Comment: I tried setting the width: ```ax.bar(df.index, df.distance,width=1)``` Nothing changes until I make it 1, then the bars touch and it looks awful.

Comment: so maybe make your plot figure bigger, try like this: plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

Comment: I am doing that like this: ```fig.set_figheight(20)
fig.set_figwidth(10)``` doesn't change the bar thickness. I think it is because the data is weekly sums.